Remove "Forum" from BuddyPress group creation step
In WordPress, I have BuddyPress and bbPress installed. bbPress creates an integration with BuddyPress where you can add forums to BuddyPress groups.
I want to remove the "Forum" step from the BuddyPress group creation step but keep the group forums active. I have tried many solutions but I can't seem to find a filter I could use.
For example, this code:
add_filter( 'groups_create_group_steps', function ( $steps ) {
    unset( $steps['group-settings'] );
    return $steps;
} );

removes the group settings from the group creation process.
This code:
function buddydev_remove_group_admin_settings() {

    if ( ! bp_is_group() ) {
        return;
    }

    bp_core_remove_subnav_item( groups_get_current_group()->slug . '_manage', 'group-settings', 'groups' );

    // reattach screen function to avoid 404.
    add_action( 'bp_screens', 'groups_screen_group_admin', 3 );
}

add_action( 'bp_template_redirect', 'buddydev_remove_group_admin_settings', 1 );

removes the group settings from the Group "Manage" menu.
Using this:
function remove_unwanted_group_creation_steps() {
    global $bp;
    if ( isset( $bp->groups->group_creation_steps['forum'] ) ) {
        unset( $bp->groups->group_creation_steps['forum'] );
    }

}
add_action( 'bp_before_create_group_content_template', 'remove_unwanted_group_creation_steps', 9999 );

removes the step but leaves the /create/step/forum/ URL active, thus messing with the custom number of steps I have.
Can you please help?
When I use:
function remove_unwanted_group_creation_steps() {
    global $bp;
    if ( isset( $bp->groups->group_creation_steps['forum'] ) ) {
        unset( $bp->groups->group_creation_steps['forum'] );
    }

}
add_action( 'bp_before_create_group_content_template', 'remove_unwanted_group_creation_steps', 9999 );

add_filter( 'groups_create_group_steps', function ( $steps ) {
    unset( $steps['group-settings'] );
    return $steps;
} );

add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if ( bp_is_group_creation_step( 'forum' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( bp_get_root_domain() . '/' . bp_get_groups_root_slug() . '/create/step/docs/' ); // Adjust to the step you want
        exit;
    }
});

The Forum step at the top is being removed but after I click the Finish button to the last step (3. Invites), I get redirected to the first step (1. Details), instead of the newly created group's default tab.
I also get a PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: next_step in [SITEPATH]\wp-content\plugins\buddypress\bp-groups\actions\create.php on line 221 after clicking the Finish button on the last step.

comment for people who propose to close this question : bbpress and buddypress are the 2 only plugins which are on-topic here then I think that this question can remain open.

Could you please try to use the given code which we need to add functions.php file of theme.
Use Case : This is to remove the Forum step from the group creation process.
add_filter('groups_create_group_steps', function( $steps ) {
    unset( $steps['forum'] );
    return $steps;
});

Use Case : This is to redirect any attempts to access the forum step URL.
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if ( bp_is_group_creation_step( 'forum' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( bp_get_group_create_slug() ); // Redirect to the first step of group creation
        exit;
    }
});

Thanks

Thanks for getting back! My first attempt was to do that but unfortunately, it didn't work. I already use
add_filter( 'groups_create_group_steps', function ( $steps ) {     unset( $steps['group-settings'] );     return $steps; } );
so after the Details step, it goes to the Forum step even with the code you have provided. Basically, my steps are 1. Details, 2.Docs, 3. Invites.
Seems like that the filters are not working for Steps that are inserted though external integrations.

Taking some hints from your reply, I have updated my original post with what partially works but has the last step redirecting to the first one!
Your code had created an undefined function bp_get_group_create_slug() error.
